# Select parent table rows whose all child table rows are selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two table with Foreign Key relation.

```
Table1 (Parent Table)
  Id

Table2 (Child Table)
  Tbl2_Id
  Tbl1_Id (References Table1)
  OptionName
  OptonValue
```

### Sample Data:

```
Table1
_____________
  Id 
------------
  1
  2
  3


Table2
_____________
Tbl2_Id | Tbl1_Id | OptionName | OptionValue
--------------------------------------------
1       |  1      | Name       | John
2       |  1      | Surname    | Mach
3       |  1      | City       | Manhattan
4       |  2      | Nimi       | John
5       |  2      | City       | Manhattan
6       |  3      | CityOfBirth| Paris
...
```

`Table2` contains dynamic data, so it keeps key/value pairs defined by users.

I want to create filtering mechanism using this dynamic data. To do this, users will define filtering criteria based on `Table2`. Rows in the `Table1` will be selected if and only if all child elements in the `Table2` is selected with the `SELECT` statement.

Such as,

```
SELECT * from Table2 WHERE (OptionName = "Name" and OptionValue = "John" ) OR (OptionName = "Surname" and OptionValue = "Mach" ) OR (OptionName = "City" and OptionValue = "Manhattan")
```

assume given SELECT returns 4 rows. 3 rows has `Tbl1_Id=1` and 1 row has `Tbl1_Id=2`

3 rows returned for `Tbl_Id1 = 1` and there are total of 3 rows with `Tbl_Id1 = 1` foreign key relation so all sub-table rows are selected for first record in Table1. Only 1 row returned for `Tbl_Id1 = 2` but this relation have total of 2 records in sub-table. No rows returned for `Tbl_Id1 = 3`
So We must return `Id=1` row of `Table1`

I am looking for a way to make a such SELECT statement which returns rows from `Table1` whose all records  are selected in sub-table `table2`

One possible way is using GROUP BY on `Table2.Tbl1_Id` and count grouped records and then compare this number with a similar GROUP BY statement which also have WHERE clause to select fitting records. Rows who returns the same number means all cases are covered.

But this is quite a heavy query for the DB. logic is needed in one of the most used feature of the application. So the query should be as light as possible.

Is there a way to make dynami data filtering lighter?

*Edit:* Sample data changed and sample query is e-written

Comment: Can you give a sample result for your sample data?

Comment: Sample data is changed a bit and sampla query given

Answer (score 1):

```
-- store the result into temp table
SELECT Tbl2_Id, Tbl1_Id, OptionName, OptionValue
INTO #Resutl1
FROM Table2 WHERE (OptionName = 'Name' and OptionValue = 'John' ) OR .......

SELECT *
FROM #Result1

-- select master table data if all childs are selected..
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE 
    -- get Ids that are selectable.
    EXISTS( SELECT 1                
                FROM #Resutl1 r 
                WHERE r.Tbl1_Id = t1.Id
            )
    -- exclude those which do not have all entries selected.
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM Table2 t2
                    LEFT JOIN #Resutl1 r ON t2.Tbl2_Id = r.Tbl2_Id
                    WHERE t2.Tbl1_Id = t1.Id
                        AND r.Tbl2_Id IS NULL
            )
```

or you can rewrite the last query using GROUP BY as,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.Tbl1_Id
            FROM Table2 t2
            LEFT JOIN #Resutl1 r ON t2.Tbl2_Id = r.Tbl2_Id
            GROUP BY t2.Tbl1_Id
            HAVING COUNT(t2.Tbl2_Id) = COUNT(r.Tbl2_Id)            
            ) ch ON ch.Tbl1_Id = t1.Id
```